# How to make my discord bot count messages in a channel and put the number into its status?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So i have a photography server and I want to make my bot count the number of photos in the photos channel and put it into its status. Ive seen many bots with changing status I think its really cool, but I cant figure it out, how I can make it... Can somebody help please?

I think I probably have to rewrite this section and maybe make another function?:

```
client.once('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity('photos | 0000 photos so far...', { type: 'WATCHING' }).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the [ClientUser#setActivity](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) method.

The simplest way to do it could be:

```js
let count = 0;

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity("photos | " + count + " photos so far...", { type: 'WATCHING' }).catch(console.error);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.guild && message.channel.id === "Your photography channel ID"){
    if(message.attachments.size != 0){ //Check if the message is an image.
      count++;
      client.user.setActivity("photos | " + count + " photos so far...", { type: 'WATCHING' }).catch(console.error);
    }
  }
});
```

Then, you can improve it by saving the count in a JSON file for example.